# Should I say : Like the one of Robin & Batman, Or, like Robin & Batman's

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which one of those following sentences is the correct and proper one to use ?

> A true friendship endures forever just like the one of Robin and Batman.
>
> A true friendship endures forever just like Robin and Batman's

in case if both of them are incorrect, what is the perfect way to use this sentence :) ?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- It's [Batman and Robin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Batman+and+Robin%2C+Robin+and+Batman%2C+Batman+%26+Robin%2C+Robin+%26+Batman&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBatman%20and%20Robin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRobin%20and%20Batman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBatman%20%26%20Robin%3B%2Cc0).
- There's a period missing from the second example.
- Friendship is [usually *between* two people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friendship+between+*%2Cfriendship+of+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfriendship%20between%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20our%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20England%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20between%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cfriendship%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20Mr.%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20France%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20those%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfriendship%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0), not *of* them.
- Superman's appeared together with Batman more than Robin has and, being comic characters, there are various arcs where any of the three are trying to kill the others.

Now, that said, "A true friendship endures forever, just like Batman and Robin's", isn't completely wrong even if "True friendship—like Batman and Robin's—lasts forever" is tighter. You want B&R to modify "friendship", not "forever".

edit: I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links, apparently, but you can google for fivethirtyeight, superman, and batman to get Walt Hickey's breakdown on the numbers showing that Robin is Batman's second love, not first.

Answer (score 0):

both answers may be correct, but it varies in different sentences.
Usually, you can use "A true friendship endures forever just like the one of Robin and Batman" in the beginning  and you can use the "A true friendship endures forever just like Robin and Batman's" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence is better grammatically speaking. There is no need for the adjective 'one' in this sentence. You could consider rephrasing your sentence as:

> Much like Batman and Robin, a true friendship lasts forever.

This has better object/subject placement.

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/one.htm

https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/subjects-and-objects/